# 'UITableView' failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource

Tags: database, swift, xcode, swift3

I updated Xcode and since then I'v problems with my dataBase.
code:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    // return the number of rows
    return leadItems.count
}

func cellForRow(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell?
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! LeadsTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.user_name_label.text = leadItems[indexPath.row].user_name
    cell.school_name_label.text = leadItems[indexPath.row].school_name

    return cell
}
```

The error that I get is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView (; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, -64}; contentSize: {375, 65802}>) failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource ()

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath is returning nil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method name for cellForRow is not correct.

Replace this line

```
func cellForRow(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell?
{
```

with

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
tableView.register(LeadsTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

This is assuming you don't have a prototype cell in the tableView in your storyboard. If you do have a prototype cell, ensure the Reuse Identifier is `"Cell"` and the custom class of the cell is `LeadsTableViewCell`; then there'll be no need to register the cell.

*UPDATE*

I just noticed your method name is wrong, it should be:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! LeadsTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.user_name_label.text = leadItems[indexPath.row].user_name
    cell.school_name_label.text = leadItems[indexPath.row].school_name

    return cell
}
```

Comment: I have a prototype "Cell" in my storyboard and I ensured everything you said but I still get the same error. Thank you though

Comment: If it helps, the thread stops at the line of the class AppDelegate

Comment: Yes I understand it now, Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a cell for your table view you must implement the data source method that is designed to provide the table view with a cell for a given row at an index path. This method is:

```
tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

Because this method is a required method you can not leave it out or you will get an error. Configure your cell in this method.